# CREATE TRIGGER TO INSERT, UPDATE AND DELETE USING VIEW - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I´m new in SQL SERVER and don´t know trigger and procuderes very well. I have this view:

```
 CREATE VIEW vwHorasTrabFunc AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
    FUNC.nome AS NomeFunc,
    sobrenome AS SobrenomeFunc,
    Salario AS salarioFunc,
    FUNC_PROJETO.cpf AS cpfFuncionario,
    FUNC_PROJETO.pno AS projetoFuncionario,
    FUNC_PROJETO.hours AS hrsTrabalhadasFuncionario
FROM funcionario AS FUNC INNER JOIN
func_proj AS FUNC_PROJETO ON FUNC.cpf = FUNC_PROJETO.cpf
```

and I want to update the employee salary after the "manager" insert a new employee in the table. How can I do that? Do I need to have one procedure to do that? I need to insert, update and delete using trigger and I really don´t know how to start it. I search into a lot of websites looking for help but I can´t do it. I really need your help please. Thank you.

update1: I did the triggers using postgres but I don´t know how to "migrate" it to sql server. In postgres is more "easy" to do because my professor teached us how to use it in postgres. Can someone help me on how to migrate, for example, this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertDep()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $insertDep$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (select * from funcionario where cpf = NEW.func_cpf AND nome = NEW.func_nome) then
        insert into dependente values(NEW.func_cpf, NEW.dep_nome, NEW.dep_gen, NEW.dep_data_nasc, NEW.relacionamento);
    ELSE
        Raise Exception 'O funcionario não está cadastrado no banco.';
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

and this:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_hpproj()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
         -- Raise Exception '%',CPFNS;
    IF NOT EXISTS (select * from funcionario where cpf = NEW.func_cpf AND nome = NEW.func_nome) 
        OR NOT EXISTS (select * from projeto where pnumero = NEW.proj_numero AND pnome = NEW.proj_nome)
          then Raise Exception 'O funcionário apontando ou o projeto não existe no banco.';
        ELSE
            insert into func_proj values(NEW.func_cpf, NEW.proj_numero, NEW.horas);
        END IF;
      RETURN NULL;
END
$BODY$
```

I tried online websites the were supposed to "convert" it, but it doesn´t did job well. Can you guys help me please? Any ideia on how can I do it?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What who's salary are you amending? If the manager is inserting a new employee, why are they not supplying the salary as part of that information?

Comment: Sorry I didn´t say all the information. The "manager" is a role that I´ll create and I´ll grant him the privilege to insert update and delete in the table funcionario which is not a view.  For example, when he insert one employee in funcionario table, the view vwHorasTrabFunc has to be update with this new information. I was thinking in something like: after updating the view, create any trigger to update the salary of the employees who have worked more than 40 hours. I was thinking in do that but I don´t know how to do that.

Comment: Why are you updating the salary of employees who worked more than 40 hours when a new employee is inserted? That just doesn't make any sense at all. And what would you update it to? You need to provide a LOT more information before anybody can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange thank you for the help. I´ll reformulate my question using your tip in the moment I arrive home. It really doesn´t make any sense updating salary after insert employee. I´ll jump this part of inserting employee and focus in do the trigger to increase employee salary who have worked more than 40 hours. It makes more sense I think,.

Comment: Moving conversation back to the Question (rather than my answer). Why do you needs triggers to do an insert? I think what we really need here is some sample data, and DDL. Provide an `INSERT` statement that the manager is likely to run, and then an expected output on what you want the data in the table to look like after the `INSERT`. I'm really struggling to visualise what you're after at the moment.

Comment: I did the triggers using postgres but I don´t know how to "migrate" it to sql server. In postgres is more "easy" to do because my professor teached us how to use it in postgres. Can someone help me on how to migrate, for exxample, this:  `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION removeDep()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $removeDep$`

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an Answer, as too indepth for a comment.

I think you're misunderstanding what a `VIEW` is. You don't "update" a view when the objects it references have values added. To quote [Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views):

> A view is a virtual table whose contents are defined by a query. Like
>   a table, a view consists of a set of named columns and rows of data.
>   Unless indexed, a view does not exist as a stored set of data values
>   in a database. The rows and columns of data come from tables
>   referenced in the query defining the view and are produced dynamically
>   when the view is referenced.

When you `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, etc, data in an bjet, that VIEW will also reflect that. As a simple example:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE SampleTable (ID int);
GO
CREATE VIEW SampleView AS
    SELECT ID, ID + 2 as ModdedID
    FROM SampleTable;
GO

INSERT INTO SampleTable VALUES (1),(2);

--This'll return the rows I just inserted.
SELECT *
FROM SampleView;
GO

DELETE FROM SampleTable
WHERE ID = 1;

--This'll return just ID 2 now..
SELECT *
FROM SampleView;
Go

--Clean up
DROP VIEW SampleView;
DROP TABLE SampleTable;
GO
```

Hope that helps.

If I've missed the aim of what your comment meant, please let me know.

Comment: It helped me to understand better the view meaning. I know that I have to do the insert, update, etc, in the table which is not the view. The main doubt is, I have to do triggers to do this insert, update and delete and I don´t know how to do that.

Comment: I just update here my doubt. Please help me if you can. I did triggers using postgres but I don´t know how to "convert" them to sql server.